# T-SQL - Insert Data into Parent and Child Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.tEmployeeData AS TABLE 
(
     FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
     LastName NVARCHAR(50),
     DepartmentType NVARCHAR(10),
     DepartmentBuilding NVARCHAR(50),
     DepartmentEmployeeLevel NVARCHAR(10),
     DepartmentTypeAMetadata NVARCHAR(100),
     DepartmentTypeBMetadata NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.EmployeeImport 
    (@tEmployeeData tEmployeeData READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @MainEmployee TABLE 
                           (EmployeeID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                            FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
                            LastName NVARCHAR(50))

    DECLARE @ParentEmployeeDepartment TABLE 
                                      (EmployeeID INT,
                                       ParentEmployeeDepartmentID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                                       DepartmentType NVARCHAR(10))

    DECLARE @ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeA TABLE 
                  (ParentEmployeeDepartmentID INT,
                   DepartmentBuilding NVARCHAR(50),
                   DepartmentEmployeeLevel NVARCHAR(10),
                   DepartmentTypeAMetadata NVARCHAR(100))

    DECLARE @ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeB TABLE 
                  (ParentEmployeeDepartmentID INT,
                   DepartmentBuilding NVARCHAR(50),
                   DepartmentEmployeeLevel NVARCHAR(10),
                   DepartmentTypeBMetadata NVARCHAR(100))

    -- INSERT CODE GOES HERE
    SELECT * FROM @MainEmployee
    SELECT * FROM @ParentEmployeeDepartment
    SELECT * FROM @ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeA
    SELECT * FROM @ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeB
END
GO

DECLARE @tEmployeeData tEmployeeData

INSERT INTO @tEmployeeData (FirstName, LastName, DepartmentType,
                            DepartmentBuilding, DepartmentEmployeeLevel,
                            DepartmentTypeAMetadata, DepartmentTypeBMetadata)
    SELECT  
        N'Tom_FN', N'Tom_LN', N'A',
        N'101', N'IV', N'Tech/IT', NULL
    UNION
    SELECT  
        N'Mike_FN', N'Mike_LN', N'B',
        N'OpenH', N'XII', NULL, N'Med' 
    UNION
    SELECT  
        N'Joe_FN', N'Joe_LN', N'A',
        N'101', N'IV', N'Tech/IT', NULL
    UNION
    SELECT  
        N'Dave_FN', N'Dave_LN', N'B',
        N'OpenC', N'XII', NULL, N'Lab' 

    EXEC EmployeeImport @tEmployeeData
GO

DROP PROC dbo.EmployeeImport 
DROP TYPE dbo.tEmployeeData
```

Notes:

- The table variables are replaced by real tables in live environment.
- `EmployeeID` and `ParentEmployeeDepartmentID` columns' values don't always match each other. Live environment has more records in the udt (`tEmployeeData`) than just 4

Goal:

- The udt (`tEmployeeData`) will be passed into the procedure
- The procedure should first insert the data into the `@MainEmployee` table (and get the `EmployeeID`s)
- Next, the procedure should insert the data into the `@ParentEmployeeDepartment` table (and get the `ParentEmployeeDepartmentID`) - note `EmployeeID` is coming from the previous output.
- Then, the procedure should split the child level data based on the `DepartmentType` ("A" = insert into @ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeA and "B" = insert into @ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeB).
- `ParentEmployeeDepartmentID` from `@ParentEmployeeDepartment` should be used when inserting data into either `@ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeA` or `@ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeB`
- The procedure should should run fast (need to avoid row by row operation)

Output:

**@MainEmployee**:

```
EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName
---------------------------------
1           Tom_FN      Tom_LN
2           Mike_FN     Mike_LN
3           Joe_FN      Joe_LN
4           Dave_FN     Dave_LN
```

**@ParentEmployeeDepartment**:

```
EmployeeID  ParentEmployeeDepartmentID  DepartmentType
-------------------------------------------------------
1           1                           A
2           2                           B
3           3                           A
4           4                           B
```

**@ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeA**:

```
ParentEmployeeDepartmentID  DepartmentBuilding  DepartmentEmployeeLevel DepartmentTypeAMetadata
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                           101                 IV                      Tech/IT
3                           101                 IV                      Tech/IT
```

**@ChildEmployeeDepartmentTypeB**:

```
ParentEmployeeDepartmentID  DepartmentBuilding  DepartmentEmployeeLevel DepartmentTypeAMetadata
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2                           OpenH               XII                     Med
4                           OpenC               XII                     Lab
```

I know I can use the `OUTPUT` clause after the insert and get `EmployeeID` and `ParentEmployeeDepartmentID`, but I'm not sure how to insert the right child records into right tables with right mapping to the parent table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: USE OUTPUT inserted.EmployedId, inserted.ParentEmployeeDepartmentType INTO TempTable (employeeid, ...) then do 2 insert statements for the child where department = A and then the next where department = b.

Comment: [You might want to look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage/34832231#34832231). My solution was to use a different UDT for each table, but it is possible to convert it to use a single UDT if you must.

Comment: @Matt, how do I, for example, prevent child data mis-mapping of ParentEmployeeDepartmentID of 2 with 4?  ZoharPeled, I'll look into that solution. The issue with this scenario is, I think, that we don't have an unique "id" field for Main/Parent tables.

Comment: Looking at it further yes you will need a temporary key.  That can be done by dumping your UDT into a temp table and assign an identity or expanding your udt to hold an identity as Zohar suggests.  Without a key you would have to rely on First & Last name combination being unique which in a small setting may be true but wouldn't hold up for long.  While I am not always a fan of MERGE I do like Zohar's use of it to maintain the relationship between the keys.

Comment: @matt thanks, I feel the same way about merge. However, that's the only way I know of to get the output from both the source table and the inserted data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my solution (based on the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832231/3094533) I've linked to in the comments):

First, you must add another column to your UDT, to hold a temporary ID for the employee:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.tEmployeeData AS TABLE 
(
     FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
     LastName NVARCHAR(50),
     DepartmentType NVARCHAR(10),
     DepartmentBuilding NVARCHAR(50),
     DepartmentEmployeeLevel NVARCHAR(10),
     DepartmentTypeAMetadata NVARCHAR(100),
     DepartmentTypeBMetadata NVARCHAR(100),
     EmployeeId int
)
GO
```

Populating it with that new employeeId column:

```
DECLARE @tEmployeeData tEmployeeData

INSERT INTO @tEmployeeData (FirstName, LastName, DepartmentType,
                            DepartmentBuilding, DepartmentEmployeeLevel,
                            DepartmentTypeAMetadata, DepartmentTypeBMetadata, EmployeeId)
SELECT  
    N'Tom_FN', N'Tom_LN', N'A',
    N'101', N'IV', N'Tech/IT', NULL, 5
UNION
SELECT  
    N'Mike_FN', N'Mike_LN', N'B',
    N'OpenH', N'XII', NULL, N'Med', 6
UNION
SELECT  
    N'Joe_FN', N'Joe_LN', N'A',
    N'101', N'IV', N'Tech/IT', NULL, 7
UNION
SELECT  
    N'Dave_FN', N'Dave_LN', N'B',
    N'OpenC', N'XII', NULL, N'Lab', 8
```

### Insert part goes here

Then, you use a table variable to map the inserted value from the employee table to the temp employee id in the data you sent to the procedure:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeidMap TABLE
(
    temp_id int,
    id int
)
```

Now, the trick is to populate the employee table with the [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement instead of an [`INSERT...SELECT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx) because you have to use values from both inserted and source data in the output clause:

```
MERGE INTO @MainEmployee USING @tEmployeeData AS sourceData ON 1 = 0 -- Always not matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (FirstName, LastName)
VALUES (sourceData.FirstName, sourceData.LastName)
OUTPUT sourceData.EmployeeId, inserted.EmployeeID 
INTO @EmployeeidMap (temp_id, id); -- populate the map table
```

From that point on it's simple, you need to join the data you sent to the `@EmployeeidMap` to get the actual employeeId:

```
INSERT INTO @ParentEmployeeDepartment (EmployeeID, DepartmentType)
SELECT Id, DepartmentType
FROM @tEmployeeData 
INNER JOIN @EmployeeidMap ON EmployeeID = temp_id
```

Now you can use the data in `@ParentEmployeeDepartment` to map the actual values in `ParentEmployeeDepartmentID` to the data you sent:

### Testing the inserts so far

```
SELECT FirstName,
     LastName,
     SentData.DepartmentType As [Dept. Type],
     DepartmentBuilding As Building,
     DepartmentEmployeeLevel As [Emp. Level],
     DepartmentTypeAMetadata As [A Meta],
     DepartmentTypeBMetadata As [B Meta],
     SentData.EmployeeId As TempId, EmpMap.id As [Emp. Id], DeptMap.ParentEmployeeDepartmentID As [Dept. Id]
FROM @tEmployeeData SentData
INNER JOIN @EmployeeidMap EmpMap ON SentData.EmployeeId = temp_id 
INNER JOIN @ParentEmployeeDepartment DeptMap ON EmpMap.id = DeptMap.EmployeeID
```

**results:**

```
FirstName   LastName    Dept. Type  Building    Emp. Level  A Meta      B Meta  TempId      Emp. Id     Dept. Id
---------   --------    ----------  --------    ----------  ------      ------  ------      ----------- -----------
Dave_FN     Dave_LN     B           OpenC       XII         NULL        Lab     8           1           1
Joe_FN      Joe_LN      A           101         IV          Tech/IT     NULL    7           2           2
Mike_FN     Mike_LN     B           OpenH       XII         NULL        Med     6           3           3
Tom_FN      Tom_LN      A           101         IV          Tech/IT     NULL    5           4           4
```

I'm sure that from this point you can easily figure out the last 2 inserts yourself.

Comment: this is brilliant!!! Thanks for the MERGE Output clause option tip (vs INSERT). Pretty cool, thank you!!