# Insert Into... Merge... Select (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could use your expertise. I have the following code:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
SELECT null, 110, Table1.ID, Table2.Column2
FROM Table1
     JOIN Table1Table2Link on Table1.ID=Table1Table2Link.Column1
     JOIN Table2 on Table1Table2Link.Column2=Table2.ID
```

Now I need to take the Inserted.ID (Table3's Identity that is generated on insert) and Table2.ID and insert them into either a temporary table or a table variable. Normally I would use the OUTPUT clause, but OUTPUT cannot get data from across different tables. Now I believe it can be done with MERGE but I am not sure how to go about it. I need something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, Table2.ID into @MyTableVar
SELECT null, 110, Table1.ID, Table2.Column2
FROM Table1
     JOIN Table1Table2Link on Table1.ID=Table1Table2Link.Column1
     JOIN Table2 on Table1Table2Link.Column2=Table2.ID
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I could not find anything.

Comment: You might need to do this by inserting the values you want to insert into a temporary table and then using `OUTPUT` to get the new output value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick is to populate the table with the `MERGE` statement instead of an `INSERT...SELECT`. That allowes you to use values from both inserted and source data in the output clause:

```
MERGE INTO Table3 USING
(
    SELECT null as col2, 
           110 as col3, 
           Table1.ID as col4, 
           Table2.Column2 as col5,
           Table2.Id as col6
    FROM Table1
    JOIN Table1Table2Link on Table1.ID=Table1Table2Link.Column1
    JOIN Table2 on Table1Table2Link.Column2=Table2.ID
) AS s ON 1 = 0 -- Always not matched
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
VALUES (s.col2, s.col3, s.col4, s.col5)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID, s.col6
INTO @MyTableVar (insertedId, Table2Id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the quick response!

Comment: Never know this.. +1

Comment: @Prdp: I found out about it myself only when I had to add multiple parent - children data. You might find [my solution to this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213008/t-sql-insert-data-into-parent-and-child-tables) helpful someday.

Comment: The wonders of T-SQL.  So glad other folks figured out this was a need!