# TSQL Merge 2 Ids into Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a stored procedure in TSQL on SQL Server 2012. When I call the stored procedure. My problem: I'm inserting the values into a table `Projects` and want to store the `inserted.ProjectId` together with `oID` from the importing table into a temporary Table; I don't store the `oID` from the importing table into the `Projects` table.

I'm referring myself to this answer:
[Insert Into... Merge... Select (SQL Server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184310/insert-into-merge-select-sql-server)

1) **Importing Table:** I'm sending a table from C# to SQL with the following values:

```
oID |  Title   | 
----+----------+
 0  | ProjectX |
 1  | ProjectY |
 2  | ProjectZ |
```

It looks like this in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [MySchema].[Project] AS TABLE
(
    oID INT,
    Title VARCHAR(100)
);

@ImportProjects MySchema.Project READONLY
```

2) **Projects Table:** I'm inserting the values into the Table Projects, and want to store the inserted.ProjectId as well as the oID from the importing Table into a temporary table:

```
ProjectId |  Title   | 
----------+----------+
33        | ProjectX |
34        | ProjectY |
35        | ProjectZ |
```

3) **Desired Output, Temporary Table**: In my temporary table I want to store the ProjectId as well as the oID from the importing table:

```
 RowID  | oID |  ProjectId   | 
--------+-----+--------------+
1       |  0  | 33           |
2       |  1  | 34           |
3       |  2  | 35           |
```

My Merge query looks like this:

```
create table Temp (ProjectId INT, oID INT)

MERGE INTO Temp USING
(
    SELECT 
        a.oID as oID,
        b.ProjectId as ProjectId
    FROM @ImportProjects a
    CROSS JOIN Projects b
) AS s ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (oID, ProjectId)
VALUES (s.oID, s.ProjectId)
OUTPUT Inserted.ProjectId, s.oID
INTO Temp(oID, ProjectId);
```

This doesn't really work... One of my problems is of course the cross join, but i dont have a link or foreign key inbetween importing table and projects table...

Do you know how to achieve this?

Thank you !! :)

Comment: Is `Project.Title` `unique`?

Comment: nope unfortunately... it's just a simple varchar(100)

Comment: Is there a set of columns in your `Project` table that uniquely identify a row other than `ProjectId` ?

Comment: In my Projects Table I have only the primary key ProjectId ProjectId INT IDENTITY(1,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `merge` attempt is a little confusing, but I think this is what you want instead:

```
create table tvp (oid int, Title varchar(100));
insert into tvp values (0,'ProjectX'),(1,'ProjectY'),(2,'ProjectZ');

create table #tmp (
    Id int not null identity(1,1)
  , oid int
  , ProjectId int
  , Title varchar(100)
);
create table Project (
    ProjectId int not null identity(33,1)
  , Title varchar(100)
);

merge into Project as Target
using tvp as Source
  on 1 = 0
when not matched then
insert (Title)
  values (source.Title)
output source.oid, Inserted.ProjectId, Inserted.Title
into #tmp;

select * from #tmp;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PIRFA34601

returns:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
|  Id | oid | ProjectId |  Title   |
+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
|   1 |   0 |        33 | ProjectX |
|   2 |   1 |        34 | ProjectY |
|   3 |   2 |        35 | ProjectZ |
+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Rextester does not support table types (because they can not be declared and used in the same transaction), so I used the table `tvp` instead.

Comment: cool, many thanks for this detailed example! ...and the real advantage is that i don't have to join on the title! :)

Answer (score 1):

replace `CROSS JOIN` with `INNER JOIN`. Foreign key is not requered for inner join

```
create table Temp (ProjectId INT, oID INT)

MERGE INTO Temp USING
(
    SELECT 
        a.oID as oID,
        b.ProjectId as ProjectId
    FROM @ImportProjects a
    INNER JOIN JOIN Projects b ON a.Title = b.Title
) AS s ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (oID, ProjectId)
VALUES (s.oID, s.ProjectId)
OUTPUT Inserted.ProjectId, s.oID
INTO Temp(oID, ProjectId);
```

Comment: thanks Mikhail, but it seems not to work unfortunately, it produces 6 rows instead of 3... hmm

Comment: It's because of merge. 3 rows inserted by `WHEN NOT MATCHED` statement, another 3 rows by `OUTPUT INTO` statement. Use simple `INSERT INTO` or insert output into another table