# SQL Inserting into table from temp table, and having ouput id inserted into temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This question is really two parts. The first part is just inserting into a real table with a temp table and having the output inserted into another temp table is not working. Here is the example.

```
Insert Into student 
        Output INSERTED.* 
        Into #StudentsOutput
Select *
From #StudentsResult
```

The error from above when I hover over it.

> Invalid Object name '#StudentsOutput'

All msdn examples I saw could do this, unless because it involves two temp tables you cannot do this.

Also note that I tried stating the columns specifically for the `student` table, and from the `#StudentsResult` table. This yielded the same results from above. So for brevity I am only showing the above tsql

The next issue is I would like the new temp table `#StudentsOutput` to contain the old student id. Since I am going to modify other tables that need the reference to the old student id. Example below.

```
Insert Into student 
    Output INSERTED.student_id, s.student_id as [old_student_id]  
    Into #StudentsOutput
Select *
From #StudentsResult as s
```

This would be perfect for what I need a lookup of the old value to the new value! Error below.

> The multi-part identifier 's.student_id' could not be bound.

Comment: For the second Issue, you can't do it using `insert`. You need to use `merge`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage/34832231#34832231) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184310/insert-into-merge-select-sql-server/41184461#41184461) one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First issue (you have to create both temp tables):

```
CREATE TABLE student(id INT);
CREATE TABLE #StudentsResult(id INT);
CREATE TABLE #StudentsOutput(id INT);


 Insert Into student 
        Output INSERTED.* 
        Into #StudentsOutput
 Select *
 From #StudentsResult;
```

**[RextesterDemo](http://rextester.com/NXQTB18108)**

From **[OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql)**:

> output_table
>
> Specifies a table that the returned rows are inserted into instead of being returned to the caller. **output_table may be a temporary table.**

Note that table should exist before you try to insert. I suppose you wanted that it works like here:

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp_table     -- in this scenario table will be created automatically
FROM ...
```

---

Second issue. You don't need aliases in output clause. Just specify column list `INTO`:

```
Insert Into student 
        Output INSERTED.student_id, INSERTED.col_name 
        Into #StudentsOutput(col1, col2)
Select *
From #StudentsResult as s;
```

Then

```
INSERTED.student_id -> col1
INSERTED.col_name   -> col2
```

Please note that you could only refer to columns from `INSERTED` pseudotable.

If you need to refer also source you have to switch to `MERGE` statement.

```
 MERGE student trg
 USING @StudentResult src
   ON ...
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT ...
 OUTPUT inserted.student_id, src.student_id
 INTO #StudentsOutput(col1, col2)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use columns from both source and target in the output clause of an insert statement, only from the [output clause of a merge statement.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184310/insert-into-merge-select-sql-server/41184461#41184461)

Comment: at the worst case scenario. I can do an inner join of the `#StudentsResult` and `#StudentsOutput` on a `rank() row over partition...` since the two tables should be identical in a row. But that just seems dirty.

Comment: It seems from your edit I will need to do use a row over partition from the Result and Output temp table. A merge wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: @christopherclark I think that your main question has been solved. I propose to ask new question based on this one, prepare input data and desired resultset. **[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com)** would help a lot.