# Use OUTPUT from INSERT INTO in UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I am populating a new table from another two tables. But I also try to use the just inserted entity ID to link it with one of the tables.

I successfully get the inserted entity ID like this:

```
INSERT INTO EngagementOverview (AccountingFirmId, AccountingFirmClientId, CompanyName, YearEnd, YearStart, AccountingFirmOfficeId)
OUTPUT inserted.id 
SELECT Engagement.AccountingFirmId, Engagement.AccountingFirmClientId, CompanyName, YearEnd, YearStart, AccountingFirmOfficeId
FROM Engagement
INNER JOIN EngagementHeader ON Engagement.EngagementHeaderId = EngagementHeader.Id
```

How could I use that in UPDATE statement to update EngagementHeader table's field?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would store the value in a table.  Then you can use the table in subsequent processing.

For instance:

```
DECLARE TABLE @ids (id int);

INSERT INTO EngagementOverview (AccountingFirmId, AccountingFirmClientId, CompanyName, YearEnd, YearStart, AccountingFirmOfficeId)
    OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @ids
    SELECT e.AccountingFirmId, e.AccountingFirmClientId, CompanyName, YearEnd, YearStart, AccountingFirmOfficeId
    FROM Engagement e INNER JOIN
         EngagementHeader eh
         ON e.EngagementHeaderId = eh.Id;
```

I'm not sure what update you want an `EngagementHeader`.

Comment: Is there a way to add more data to the @ids table together with OUTPUT. I would love to have id and EngagementHeader.Id in the same row

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis . . . I believe you can only add columns in the *output* table.  This is a pain.  One solution may be that the other columns identify a unique key and you can query them, with `EngagementHeader` afterwards.

Comment: @IrmantasŽelionis Not exactly clear what you want, but `merge` allows `output` of columns beyond those which are being inserted. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184310/insert-into-merge-select-sql-server) answer may be helpful.