# Inserting rows from one database table into two different tables in another database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to add about 600 records from one database to another one.

The first part inserts from a select like this:

```
INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSignals(CstarID, StarName, SystemName, StarSystemCount, SuperNova, DateCreated)
SELECT NEWID(), startName, systemName, 1, 1,  getDate() 
FROM AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals 
WHERE rangeICW = 5
```

This is where it gets tricky and I don't know how to do it.

So for each row inserted above, I need to also insert related data into another table.

The `NEWID()` above would be used to insert a row and then I'd need to insert the `starCoordinates` as well from `AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals` and it would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSources(CstarID, starCoordinates,  isVerified)
VALUES('1150C651-5D9A-4C13-9BE7-EF4AZ2549112', 'R.A. 13h 27m, DEC. -47deg, 29m', 1)
```

`starCoordinates` is also from the same table and row that I'm SELECTing from(AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals)

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: It sounds like a job for the [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You can add it to the first `insert` to capture the assigned id's. If you need to capture both the source and destination table id's to correlate the data then you can use a `merge` rather than `insert` for the first operation.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41184461/92546) answer for more information.

Comment: If this is an ongoing thing, check out triggers

Comment: @HABO So I would do the merge on RelayMapper.dbo.radioSignals then an insert on RelayMapper.dbo.radioSources?

Comment: `INSERT` and `UPFATE` also support `OUTPUT` clause, so unless you need to do an actual merge you do not necessarily have to do one.

Comment: @Alex I just need to update two different tables from the same select query and using the same NEWID().  I'm not quite sure how to do that.  thanks

Comment: MSDN: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124847/best-way-to-get-last-identity-inserted-in-a-table
Stack Overflow: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124847/best-way-to-get-last-identity-inserted-in-a-table  ,

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell If you use an `insert` to copy data into `radioSignals` then you can `output` any of the columns that you inserted into another table, e.g. a table variable. You can use that to get the new `CstarID` for the `insert` into `radioSources`. If you need to get `radioSources` from the other database then you'll need to be able to match the source database `CstarID` values with the newly assigned ones. Replacing the initial `insert` with a `merge` will let you `output` inserted columns and other source columns, e.g. the original `CstarID` values. That gives you the old to new mapping.

Comment: @Alex The issue with `insert` and `output` is that you can only output columns that you insert. If you need to create a mapping table from source `CstarID` values to destination values assigned by `NewId()` then you need to output the source value which is not being inserted. Using `merge` allows `output` access to source fields that are not inserted, You could even `join` the source tables (_assumption_) and use `merge`/`output` to produce the new `radioSources` rows with the _old_ to _new_ mapping in a table variable or temporary table, then just `insert` them with the new `CstarID`.

Comment: Another option is to copy all data from `AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals` into a temp table and at the same time assign GUIDS and then insert from this table into your destination tables. This way you already have all of the mapping data available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OUTPUT clause to get the inserted values and then use them to insert into another table.

```sql
DECLARE @insertedId TABLE(CStartID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSignals(CstarID, StarName, SystemName, StarSystemCount, SuperNova, DateCreated)
OUTPUT inserted.CStarID INTO @insertedId
SELECT NEWID(), startName, systemName, 1, 1,  getDate() 
FROM AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals 
WHERE rangeICW = 5;

--with values clause
INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSources(CstarID, starCoordinates,  isVerified)
SELECT CStarId
'R.A. 13h 27m, DEC. -47deg, 29m', 1
FROM @insertedId;

--WITH select clause
INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSources(CstarID, starCoordinates,  isVerified)
SELECT i.CStarId, rs.starCoordinates, 1
FROM AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals AS rs
CROSS JOIN  @insertedId AS i
WHERE rs.rangeICW = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, will this work on multiple rows at the same time?  For example if I needed to insert a few hundred records into RelayMapper.dbo.radioSignals, would it also insert the CStarId values into RelayMapper.dbo.radioSources? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It will work as it is a table variable and can hold many rows. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

One option is to copy all data from `AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals` into a temp table and at the same time assign GUIDS and then insert from this table into your destination tables.

```
SELECT NEWID() AS CstarID, *
INTO #TempTable
FROM AISourceMapper.dbo.radioSignals 
WHERE rangeICW = 5

INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSignals( CstarID, StarName, SystemName, StarSystemCount, SuperNova, DateCreated )
SELECT CstarID, startName, systemName, 1, 1,  getDate() 
FROM #TempTable

INSERT INTO RelayMapper.dbo.radioSources( CstarID, starCoordinates,  isVerified )
SELECT CstarID, starCoordinates,  isVerified
FROM #TempTable
```