# Replicate Data in same table with modified Relations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

We had a requirement to copy data from one company to another, for this we need to replicate all the data present in one table into the same table but with a different company id

**Table 1: Employee**

```
FName      Id   Department  CatId  CompanyId
Pratik      1    1            4       1
Praveen     2    2            3       1
Nilesh      3    2            3       1
```

**Table 2 : ComboValues**

```
Id   Fieldname  FieldValue  CompanyId
1    Department     IT        1
2    Department     HR        1
3    Category       Staff     1
4    Category       Manager   1
```

I want to replicate all the data present in table 1 & table 2 in the same table with Updated companyid

For Table2 below is the query => It is working as Expected

```
INSERT INTO ComboValues (Fieldname,FieldValue, CompanyId)
(SELECT Fieldname,FieldValue,2 WHERE Companyid = 1)
```

Result

**Table 2 : ComboValues**

```
Id   Fieldname  FieldValue  CompanyId
1    Department     IT        1
2    Department     HR        1
3    Category       Staff     1
4    Category       Manager   1
5    Department     IT        2
6    Department     HR        2
7    Category       Staff     2
8    Category       Manager   2
```

Problem :

**But for Table1 I'm not able to do the same because of updated ID values of Department and Category present in table 2**

Expected Result
**Table 1: Employee**

```
FName      Id   Department  CatId  CompanyId
Pratik      1    1            4       1
Praveen     2    2            3       1
Nilesh      3    2            3       1
Pratik      4    5            8       2
Praveen     5    6            7       2
Nilesh      6    6            7       2
```

I can do the same in C# by using loops which I want to avoid and do same with SQL query only

Comment: You can adapt the technique I've shown in my answer to [T-SQL - Insert Data into Parent and Child Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213008/t-sql-insert-data-into-parent-and-child-tables/38217498#38217498) to insert the correct newly-created ids into the Employee table. I'm not voting to close as a duplicate because I don't want to use my sql/sql-server gold badge dupe-hammer but I think it is a good candidate for a dupe vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
WITH tmp_table AS
(
    SELECT o.id AS id_old, n.id AS id_new
    FROM combovalues o
    INNER JOIN combovalues n 
    ON o.fieldname = n.fieldname AND o.fieldvalue = n.fieldvalue
    WHERE o.companyid = 1 AND n.companyid = 2
)
INSERT INTO employee (fname, department, catid, companyid)
SELECT fname, d.id_new, c.id_new, 2
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN tmp_table d
ON e.department = d.id_old
LEFT JOIN tmp_table c
ON e.catid = c.id_old
WHERE companyid = 1;
```

Tested in [rextester](https://rextester.com/ELSN54467)

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Good thing I didn't close the question as a duplicate. +1.

Comment: Bach, do you have time to view my similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54221218/sql-server-duplicate-clone-records-and-all-of-its-children-rows-from-other-tab

Comment: @AnhBảy sr I'm in busy this time, will check later. Hope you got your answer soon!

Comment: @AnhBảy you could check for comment in your question.