# T-SQL - Insert set into multiple constrained tables on linked server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, bulkinsert, linked-server

So, I have a data set on server "A" and two tables ("t1", "t2") on linked server "B".
I cannot modify server "B" schema.
What I am trying to achieve is: insert first two data set (non-identity) columns into [B].[t1] which should generate identity index value, and then add second two, also non-identity, columns into [B].[t2], which contains column MsgId that should map to corresponding row in [B].[t2].
[A visual version of how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywOOB.png)

It seems that I cannot use OUTPUT nor SCOPE_IDENTITY() on a linked server (both return nothing).

My question is so: Is there a way to add data from server A to server B without modifying latter?

My current solution involves cursors and creating a stored procedure on a remote server, but I feel like I am doing it completely wrong and reinventing wheel in the process. Also, modifying database structure is a painful process involving lots of paperwork.

Comment: If you can create stored procedures on the linked server, I think that [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38217498/3094533) can help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is ETL (Extract, transform, load) and using a tool like SSIS helps to do that much cleaner and more maintainable.