# Adding a collection of User-Defined Table Types in a stored procedure to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable

I am wondering if anyone can help me or point in the correct direction as I trying to figure out is it possible to put collection of User-Defined Table types inside another I am trying to bulk insert a collection of parent and child tables into a SQL Server database. I can do this individually, but I am wondering can this be done with 100 orders in one go, rather than sending many inserts in a loop and having to split the list orders into individual orders then split the order and it order detail into two separate data tables.

I can not seem to figure out how to adjust the below, to send a collection of orders rather than one at a time. Without having to split them but also ensuring it will still insert the correct child rows to the correct parent record. As one order can have unlimited amount of lines detail lines.

User-Defined Table Types

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ordertype
AS TABLE
(
    orderdate datetime,
    ordernumber varchar(50) not null,
    totalprice       decimal(18,0) not null,
);

CREATE TYPE dbo.orderdetailtype
AS TABLE
(
    productname varchar(50) not null,
    price       decimal(18,0) not null,
    qty         int not null
);
```

The stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tes]
                 @ordertype          ordertype       ReadONLY,
                 @orderdetailtype    orderdetailtype ReadONLY

AS
BEGIN

   SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @orderid INT 

    INSERT INTO dbo.orders (orderdate, ordernumber, totalprice  )
    SELECT orderdate, ordernumber, totalprice                                     
    FROM @ordertype;

    SET @orderid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SELECT @orderid

    INSERT INTO dbo.orderdetails( productname, price, qty )
    SELECT productname, price, qty
    FROM @orderdetailtype;

    return @orderid

END
```

The call using c#

```
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_tes";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ordertype", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = order;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@orderdetailtype", SqlDbType.Structured).Value = orderdetails;
            SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Returns", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Can you add `ordernumber` column to your `orderdetailtype` table type?  If so, you could loop through `ordertype` and each time through insert from `orderdetailtype` where the `ordernumber` match.  As it is now, you have no discernible relation between your `orders` and `orderdetails` table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I could if I had to, could you provide an example of the loop and inserting from it.

Comment: Check out my answer to a [similar question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a connecting field for both table-types. Maybe the order number? Use the [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(OUTPUT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true) clause to return the new ids in a table variable and join it to the second parameter table.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ordertype
AS TABLE
(
    orderdate   datetime,
    ordernumber varchar(50)    not null,
    totalprice  decimal(18, 2) not null
)

CREATE TYPE dbo.orderdetailtype
AS TABLE
(
    orderNumber varchar(50)    not null,
    productname varchar(50)    not null,
    price       decimal(18, 2) not null,
    qty         int            not null
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.orders
(
    orderid     INT IDENTITY(1, 1)  not null, 
    orderdate   datetime,
    ordernumber varchar(50)    not null,
    totalprice  decimal(18, 2) not null
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.orderdetails
(
    orderid     INT            not null, 
    productname varchar(50)    not null,
    price       decimal(18, 2) not null,
    qty         int            not null
)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tes]
  @ordertype       dbo.ordertype       READONLY,
  @orderdetailtype dbo.orderdetailtype READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  DECLARE
    @newIds AS TABLE (
      ordernumber VARCHAR(50),
      orderId     INT
    )

  INSERT
    INTO dbo.orders (orderdate, ordernumber, totalprice)
  OUTPUT inserted.ordernumber, inserted.orderid INTO @newIds
         SELECT orderdate, ordernumber, totalprice                                     
           FROM @ordertype

  INSERT 
    INTO dbo.orderdetails(orderId, productname, price, qty)
         SELECT T1.orderId, T2.productname, T2.price, T2.qty
           FROM @newIds T1
                INNER JOIN @orderdetailtype T2
                        ON T1.orderNumber = T2.orderNumber

  SELECT *
    FROM @newIds
END

GO

DECLARE
  @ordertype       dbo.ordertype,
  @orderdetailtype dbo.orderdetailtype

INSERT 
  INTO @ordertype
       SELECT GETDATE(), '2016/0001', 22.48
       UNION
       SELECT GETDATE(), '2016/0002', 19.98
INSERT 
  INTO @orderdetailtype
       SELECT '2016/0001', 'Sql Guide',  9.99, 1
       UNION
       SELECT '2016/0001', 'Introducing Microsoft SQL Server 2016', 12.49, 1
       UNION
       SELECT '2016/0002', 'Sql Guide',  9.99, 2

EXEC [dbo].[sp_tes] @ordertype, @orderdetailtype

SELECT *
  FROM dbo.orders
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.orderdetails
```