# In C#,using select SCOPE_IDENTITY() causes deadlock?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

By replacing `@@identity` with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` I am getting a deadlock, though using `scope_identity()` is recommended by Microsoft.

In my C# method, I have lot of insert queries for master and it's details. Does anyone know why calling `scope_identity()` would cause timeout or deadlock issues?

Comment: why exactly `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`? may be cause in `INSERT`?

Comment: please share deadlock graph

Comment: if using sql server 2008,you can check below answer ,to get deadlock graph,subject to some constraints:http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10646/31995

Comment: there should some another region for dead lock no way it could be SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: previously using @@identity and IDENT_CURRENT(table),there is no problem,but after replacing it with scope_identity creates timeout and deadlock.

Comment: I have posted a [table valued parameters based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage/34832231#34832231) to inserting many parent-child records in a single stored procedure. You might find it useful.

Comment: moreover,We are using sql server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I think this situation can be about your code which executes parallel Inserts to table. 
Pinal Dave has an article about SCOPE_IDENTITY's bug about parallel inserts 
You should read it here ; http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/24/sql-server-2008-scope_identity-bug-with-multi-processor-parallel-plan-and-solution/

Comment: I go through this article,but we are using sql server 2012.but still I am clueless that what is the problem?

Comment: so what happens if you follow the advice in the article, does that fix anything?  for example sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 1;

Comment: @Cato,Will it solve the problem by setting max degree of parallelism?

Comment: I'd suggest using some of the articles suggestion, such as replacing SCOPE_IDENTITY with the OUTPUT method described - I can't say for sure, because I'm not familiar with your project, but it looks like the info the answerer gave you is likely to be related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the solutions I applied for deadlock in my scenario :

1. deadlock is solved by setting row lock on insert and update query.
2. Also I found some uncommitted transactions in code which is also
   another   factor for creating deadlock.
3. setting sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 1 as well
   replacing scope_identity with @@identity.