# Inserting data into several tables via stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I got a performance issue with an import task (user need to import new data into the system) and could use little help.

The data within the database looks like this:

Table `Categories`:

Columns:

- `Id int primary key identity(1,1)`
- `Code nvarchar(20) not null`
- `RootId int not null`
- `ParentId int not null`

Table `CategoryNames`:

Columns:

- `CategoryId int not null foreign key references Category (Id)`
- `LanguageId int not null foreign key references Language (Id)`
- `Name nvarchar(100)`

Currently it's working like this: for each row

- Create connection to database
- Call stored procedure with data[i]
- Close connection

I already got rid of the creating and closing connection for each row of data. But it's still not good enough.

Currently the task needs round about 36 minutes to insert ~22000 categories.
The stored procedure looks like this:

```
procedure Category_Insert 
     (@code nvarchar(20),
      @root int,
      @parent int,
      @languageId int,
      @name nvarchar(100),
      @id int output)
as
     set nocount on

     insert into Categories (Code, RootId, ParentId) 
     values (@code, @root, @parent)

     select id = scope_identity()

     insert into CategoryNames (CategoryId, LanguageId, Name) 
     values (@id, @languageId, @name)
```

Got any advice how I can speed up the performance of that task?

I would love to use bulk insert or something like that, but how would I realize the logic of the stored procedure with bulk insert?

Or is the any other way to speed this up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to perform nested bulk inserts with scope\_identity() usage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage)

Comment: This is inserting each row one at a time, right?  Can you not import the data all at once?

Comment: Is this a one time only update or something that is to be done multiple times on a periodic basis?

Comment: @JohnH: This task is executed multiple times, I've been told several times a week.

Comment: @iamdave: Yes correct, each row is inserted one at a time. Trying to speed it up without rewriting the whole task.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out. Maybe that's exactly what I need.

Comment: You seem to need an ETL (Extract Transfer and Load) program. Have you searched SO using the "etl" key word?