# SQL table 2 table insert with foreign/primary keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, primary-key

i have 2 tables. One is Order header the other one is order lines.
Order header:

```
OrderID Customer IntegrationID(Identity auto Incremental)
```

Order lines :

```
OrderID Itemid IntegrationID
```

The thing i want to do:
i run a stored procedure which populates these 2 tables with data and i want the order line to have the same IntegrationID as the order header. For example when i insert to order header:

```
OrderID Customer IntegrationID(Identity auto Incremental)
500       5          1
501       4          2
```

And in the order lines i want to have the data like this:

```
OrderID Itemid IntegrationID
 500     101         1
 500     102         1
 501     102         2
```

Any ideas how can i achieve that? Orderheader and orderlines are linked via ORDERID field.

Comment: what is initial data in Order Line table?

Comment: Its orderid and Itemid

Comment: What you have tried, show your query

Comment: Why not just insert into order line immediately after order header in the stored proc? Can you include stored proc code.

Comment: stored procedure is simple it just inserts lines into salestable and saleslines: iNSERT into SalesHeader  OrderID,Customer select orderid,customer  from SalesTable insert into OrderLines OrderId itemid select orderid,itemid from SalesLine. T

Comment: The reason i want to to this, is that these records are processed by other system. And there may be cases that if an order is modified for a couple of times in the system here it would appear multiple times. So that's why i want to separate them at each new insert.

Comment: If you want to insert **multiple orders** with the corresponding order lines, you can use [the technique I've posted here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage/34832231#34832231)  
If you want to insert a single order, then it's much simpler.

Comment: From where do you insert these records? Can you use table valued parameters?

Comment: Im recieving records from a view

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple,
For Example In Your Stored Procedure you insert record in table "Order Header"

```
Insert into (col1,col2) values ("val1","val2")
```

then you should use the following query to insert into table "Order Line"

```
SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Then insert this @new_identity in the query

```
Insert into Order Line (OrderID Itemid IntegrationID) values 
("value1","value2",@new_identity)
```

but make sure these both query executes in same stored procdure
if you have individual SP for both then you should have return from the first SP

Comment: Thank you for reply but ,correct me if I'm wrong, but this only works then one order is inserted. Am I correct?