# T-SQL Increment Id after Insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 using T-SQL. My problem: I have several SWOTs (e.g. for a specific client) holding several SWOTParts (strengths, weaknesses, opportunities, and threats). I store the values in a table **Swot** as well as in another table **SwotPart**.
My foreign Key link is SwotId in SwotPart, thus 1 Swot can hold N SwotParts. Hence, I store the SwotId in every SwotPart.
I can have many Swots and now need to set the SwotId correctly to create the foreign key. I set the SwotId using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` unfortunately it only takes the last SwotId from the DB.
I'm looking for something like a for loop to increment the SwotId after each insert on the 1st insert.

```
DECLARE @SwotId INT = 1;    

-- 1st insert
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO [MySchema].[SWOT]([SwotTypeId]) // Type can be e.g. a sepcific client
SELECT SwotTypeId
FROM @SWOTS

SET @SwotId = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); // currently e.g. 7, but should increment: 1, 2, 3...

-- 2nd insert
SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO [MySchema].[SwotPart]([SwotId], [FieldTypeId], [Label]) // FieldType can be e.g. Streangh
SELECT @SwotId, FieldTypeId, Label
FROM @SWOTPARTS
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? What could I use instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you want to insert multiple `@swots` and `@swotparts` how do you know which  `@swotparts` goes to which  `@swots` ?

Comment: I can't see your insert query for `Swot` table, whose id will be used as foreign key in  `SwotPart` table. you can't put arbitrary value in a Foreign key column. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826450/fastest-way-to-perform-nested-bulk-inserts-with-scope-identity-usage/34832231#34832231

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**`output`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) the `inserted` rows into a temporary table, then join your `@swotparts` to the temporary table based on the natural key (whatever unique column set ties them together beyond the `SwotId`). This would solve the problem with resorting to loops or cursors, while also overcoming the obstacle of doing a single `swot` at a time.

```
set nocount, xact_abort on;

create table #swot (SwotId int, SwotTypeId int);

insert into MySchema.swot (SwotTypeId) 
  output inserted.SwotId, inserted.SwotTypeId into #swot
select SwotTypeId
from @swots;

insert into MySchema.SwotPart(SwotId, FieldTypeId, Label)
select s.SwotId, p.FieldTypeId, p.Label
from @swotparts p
  inner join #swot s
    on p.SwotTypeId = p.SwotTypeId;
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! The solution with the temporary table was what I was kind of looking for to store the Id

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cant comment so I`ll leave you an answer hopefully to clarify some things:

- Since you need to create the correct foreign key I don`t understand
  why do you need to increment a value instead of using the id inserted
  into the SWOT table.
- I suggest returning the inserted id using the **SCOPE_IDENTITY** right after the insert statement and use it for you insert into the swot parts (there is plenty of info about it and how to use it)

  ```
   DECLARE @SwotId INT;    
  -- 1st insert
  INSERT INTO [MySchema].[SWOT]([SwotTypeId]) // Type can be e.g. a sepcific client
  SET @SwotId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

  -- 2nd insert
  INSERT INTO [MySchema].[SwotPart]([SwotId], [FieldTypeId], [Label])
  SELECT @SwotId, FieldTypeId, Label
  FROM @SWOTPARTS
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your help