# SQL generate unique id when copying multiple records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ApplyExistingImageAcrossModel
@capidfrom int,
@capidto int,
@type int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @imageid uniqueidentifier

INSERT INTO ImageMetaData
(ImageId,CapId,[Type],Source,DateAdded,OriginalFileName,OriginalUrl,isDefault,Height,Width,ViewType,CapImageId,islive)
SELECT @imageid,@capidto,@type,source,GETDATE(),originalfilename,originalurl,isdefault,height,width,viewtype,capimageid,islive 
FROM ImageMetaData 
WHERE [type] = @type AND capid = @capidfrom

INSERT INTO ImageData
(ImageId,ImageBinary)
SELECT @imageid,ImageBinary 
FROM ImageData A
LEFT JOIN ImageMetaData B
ON A.ImageId = B.ImageId
WHERE B.[type] = @type 
AND B.capid = @capidfrom

END
```

The problem is that the select can return multiple records for a particular `capid`, and I want to copy them all, but each record needs a unique `@imageid` which i'm only generating once, I need to use that `imageid` in both tables.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a duplicate or not - If it is please let me know:https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832231/3094533

Comment: I would suggest using better aliases than A, B. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 Have you considered using the OUTPUT clause from your initial insert? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Instead creating one variable, declare table variable to store the unique IDs. Then, use `OUPUT` clause to record all the IDs. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE 
(
    @imageid uniqueidentifier
);

INSERT INTO ImageMetaData(ImageId,CapId,[Type],Source,DateAdded,OriginalFileName,OriginalUrl,isDefault,Height,Width,ViewType,CapImageId,islive)
OUTPUT inserted.ImageId
INTO @DataSource (@imageid)
SELECT NEWID(),@capidto,@type,source,GETDATE(),originalfilename,originalurl,isdefault,height,width,viewtype,capimageid,islive 
FROM ImageMetaData 
WHERE [type] = @type AND capid = @capidfrom
```

Now, in the `@DataSource` table we have the inserted  `imageID`s. Do with them whatever you want.